# How to get page title (<title></title>) in a different order?

Tags: title, wp-title, theme-twenty-seventeen

I am trying to figure out, how to change the current order of the page title (displayed on the tab or browser windows).
Currently, it is `<page_title> - <site_title>`. The site title is exactly the one, which is set under settings/site title. I would like to have `<site_title> - <page_title>` instead. I am modifying twentyseventeen theme and there is a `wp_head` call. But I can't find how to easily change the order.

Comment: you likely have yoast installed.  Check there.

Comment: I didn't install Yoast.

Comment: Can I ask why? There's a reason *every* website does it this way.

Comment: I thought, I wouldn't need it for such a simple task.